# ArcGIS Feature Service - Restrict Editing to Specific Feature Classes

Tags: arcgis-server, editing

In ArcGIS Server 10.1, is there a way to restrict editing rights on a Feature Service so that only specific feature classes can be edited?

Answer (score 3):

You could create two different services. A feature service for all of your editable feature classes and a map service (which is read only) for the non-editable feature classes.

You could also look into [ownership-based access controls](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Feature_service_permissions_and_editor_tracking/0154000004p0000000/), which will limit access based on the owner of the data.